# Check if element exists within DIV

Tags: jquery

I want to, on click, move an element inside a div unless it's already inside it. I was thinking something like...

Click tag > If element is in div do nothing > Else move element into div

http://jsfiddle.net/establish/Xhhe8/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">Art</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">Computing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">Design</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="crate">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.tag').on('click', function(event) {

if ($('#crate').has(this)) {
    // do nothing
}

else {

    $(this).appendTo('#crate');
}
});
```

It doesn't work. Also not sure how to represent 'do nothing', usually I just use a singular IF statement so no need to represent it. Can I do this to 'do nothing' and disable the click?

```
$(this).off();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it..

```
$('.tag').on('click', function(event) {

    var self = $(this);
    if (self.closest('#crate').length) {
        // do nothing
    }
    else {
        self.appendTo('#crate');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 11):

Gaby's answer will work, but I'd prefer structuring it without the empty `if` block like this:

```
$('.tag').on('click', function(event) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.closest('#crate').length == 0) {
        self.appendTo('#crate');
    }
});
```

Comment: good point. I assumed that he might eventually want to remove the element if it is inside..

Comment: I did want to remove it! Thanks, should have stated that.

Comment: @DanChristian - remove what and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

You usually represent the opposite of an `if` statement with `if not` (i.e. replacing `==` with `!=`):

```
$('.tag').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).parent().get(0) != $('#crate').get(0)) {
        $(this).appendTo('#crate');
    }
});
```

Instead of checking whether the element exists in the parent, why not compare parents?

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xhhe8/3/**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (I just adjusted a bit of your code):

```
$('.tag').on('click', function(event) {

    if ($('#crate').find(this).length) {
        // do nothing
    }

    else {

        $(this).appendTo('#crate');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Me to!

Or this:

```
$('.tag').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).parent().attr('id') != "crate") {
        $(this).appendTo('#crate')
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/establish/Xhhe8/

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, based on Alex's answer:

```
  $('.tag').on('click', function(event) {    
    if ($('#crate').find(this).length < 1) {
       $(this).appendTo('#crate');
       $(this).off('click')
    }
   });
```

I think the if clause makes more sense in this case; we're just checking if the crate element has 'this'.

The semantics of "if ($('#crate').has(this))" is misleading because we're expecting a boolean value when it actually returns an empty array, which evaluates to true in Javascript. So even if "#crate" has the actual element or not, the if condition is always true.